# ext4 won't be extended

Tags: debian, ext4, gparted, size

I manualy installed Debian with encrypted LVM,  now I'm trying to extend ext4 from gparted Live, but it won't extend it and I don't understand why for the moment, here are my partitions

[image: parts]

[image: size]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extend a partition which is directly surrounded by other partitions. You have to "move" `/dev/sda4` after `/dev/sda5`. You can do this with cut and paste. Paste the partition after your encrypted one (at the begin of the free space). After this you can extend it.

Comment: Thanks, but now I can't boot (it enter grub rescue), I guess it's because now the ext4 partition is not named dev4 anymore isn't it ? Also I don't have the "cut" option, I had to copy/paste then delete

Comment: This means the partition you moved was maybe your `/boot`. If it is so, for being able to boot again you have to repair your `grub`. Use the [how-to](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) from another question at ask-ubuntu to repair it with a live-system. When you did it correct, you should be able to boot your system again.

Comment: Thanks a lot but when I try to install grub it says me it can't fint the canonical path for /boot/grub...